# R Displaying Incorrect Significance Level?

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

In the following output, *predictor* variable has a p-value of 0.001809 but is indicated to be significant at the 0.001 level as it has '**' displayed next to it. Surely given that the p-value is greater than 0.001 means it isn't significant at the 0.001 level? Rather, it would be significant at the 0.01 level?

[image]

Comment: This way of thinking is no longer considered to be good statistical practice.  See for example https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that it is presented is quite counterintuitive, as it is shown as a set of intervals even though it looks like a list. 
However, it means that:

*** is used for values BETWEEN 0 and 0.001 
** is used for values BETWEEN 0.001 and 0.01 
* is used for values BETWEEN 0.01 and 0.05 
. is used for values BETWEEN 0.05 and 0.1 
empty character is used for values BETWEEN 0.1 and 1

Comment: Yes. Another example of R being "expert friendly".

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thank you. But then would I interpret this as p-value being statistically significant at the 0.01% level or the 0.1% level?

Comment: ** means your value is between 0.001 and 0.01. Therefore, it is significant at the 0.01 level.

Comment: When referred to as a percentage significance level, would the 0.01 level be the 1% significance level? Just as the 0.05 level is considered the 5% significance level.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.